# How avoid using the mobile UI on tablet device in split-screen mode

Tags: android

I get confused about the support `multi-window` mode on tablet device.

I have Mobile UI and Tablet UI. It was switched on `*-sw600dp` resource idiom.

```
values : is_tablet = false  
values-sw600dp : is_tablet = true
```

And my apps with completely different layouts for mobile and tablet.

Google says

> Apps with completely different layouts for mobile and tablet should
>   avoid using the mobile UI on tablet in split-screen mode.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/split-screen.html#split-screen-layout

But, How can I recognized the physical device figure?(Tablet device or Phone device)
Can not use `*-sw600dp` resource idiom, because app is erroneously running Mobile UI when launched in split screen mode.

Please help. How avoid using the mobile UI on tablet in my apps.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: you mean you want different layout files for mobile & tablet?

Comment: @Pooya yes. i have 2 layout files in `layout`(Mobile UI) and `layout-sw600dp`(Tablet UI).  
If non-split-screen-mode then app is running Tablet UI.  
But if split-screen-mode then app is running Mobile UI.  
For my case, Google says "avoid using the mobile UI on tablet in split-screen mode."  
I interpreted as they should running Tablet UI on split-screen-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Self-solve.

Use Application's context then calculated `*-sw600dp` with physical device screen size. 
But use Activity`s context then calculated with PhoneWindow size.
(Maybe this way is not recommendation...)